# Swift-Deletion in Core Data with multiple selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

In Core Data application, we can swipe to delete a row, but I want to delete multiple rows by selecting them.

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

I have done the above and I have also implemented the usual deletion method. I also tried something like this.

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
}

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let entry: DiaryEntry = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DiaryEntry
    let coreDataStack: CoreDataStack = CoreDataStack.defaultStack
    coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(entry)
    coreDataStack.saveContext()
}
  func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

    var multipleSelection = false

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {

    case .Insert :
        if indexPath != newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }

    case .Delete :
        if (multipleSelection == true) {
            let selectedRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
            for selectionIndex in selectedRows! {
                let indicesOfItemsToDelete = NSMutableIndexSet()

                indicesOfItemsToDelete.addIndex(selectionIndex.row)

                let entry: DiaryEntry = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(selectionIndex) as! DiaryEntry
                let coreDataStack: CoreDataStack = CoreDataStack.defaultStack
                coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(entry)
                coreDataStack.saveContext()
            }
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(selectedRows!, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        } else {
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }

    case .Update :
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    case .Move :
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        if indexPath != newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }

    }
}

   func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {

    case .Insert :
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    case .Delete :
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    case .Update :

        //let range: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, (self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count)!)
        self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    default:
        break
    }

}
```

When I press the edit method, I set the tableView's editing to true and after selection, when I press delete button, following is the code.

```
 let selectedRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
 multipleSelection = true
 for selectionIndex in selectedRows! {
                tableView(tableView, commitEditingStyle: .Delete, forRowAtIndexPath: selectionIndex)
            }
 self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(selectedRows!, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(selectedRows!, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

But, I am getting an error: CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of .....

Can, someone please tell me the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't delete by asking the table view to delete (commit editing type). Get the list of managed objects to delete and delete them from the context yourself, then tell the table view they're gone (which you already do). Also, don't reload the rows after you tell the table they're gone.

Comment: So, I think I did that. I put the "for selectionIndex in selectedRows! {....}" code in delete action method and removed other code. But, the error is still same.

Comment: No, I am deleting the object using context. Is that wrong?

Comment: for selectionIndex in selectedRows! {
                    
                    let entry: DiaryEntry = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(selectionIndex) as! DiaryEntry
                    let coreDataStack: CoreDataStack = CoreDataStack.defaultStack
                    coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(entry)
                    coreDataStack.saveContext()
                }

Comment: Get all the managed objects first and then iterate the objects, don't iterate index paths, as you delete you invalidate the index paths...

Comment: I understand now. It's working but not yet 100%. It deletes a row from 1 section, but if I am selecting multiple rows from more than 1 section. It shows the error. attempt to delete row 1 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update.

Comment: Although, when I restarted the app, those rows were also deleted, guess I have to reload sections, but the problem is, how do I get the indexSet of all the sections?

Comment: you'd need to calculate it, the issue is if you delete all the rows from a section then the FRC will also delete the section so you need to tell the table about it

Comment: I know, but I am also getting this error: "attempt to delete and reload the same index path". I know there are new index Paths, but in controller(didChangeObject), we have newIndexPath parameter in the method, but now, we have only those indexes that we are deleting/ selected. So, why this error?

Comment: in this operation you're only deleting, yes? and are you deleting a section but there is another section after it? if it's a complex delete then you kinda need to just reload the table because the individual deletes are just too complex to be worth it...

Comment: yeah, i have multiple sections.